# Is there a way to change zoom level and font size on different monitors?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using both 1920*1080 and 1366*768 monitors. I want to change the zoom level and font size for the second monitor. Is it possible?

Comment: if you are using windows 10,you can do it. Link https://www.howtogeek.com/304036/how-to-adjust-scaling-for-different-monitors-in-windows-10/

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to customize VSCode in settings, `User Settings` and `Workspace Settings`. I assume that you want to use two windows of VSCodes on different screens. So, in the first window, you can change the zoom level and font size in `User Settings`. The second one, you can change the settings in the `Workspace Settings`.

[image]